# Elasticsearch returns NullPointerException during inner_hits query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index, which stores a nested document. I wanna see this nested documents, for this purpose I used 'inner_hits' in request, but elastic returns nullPointerException. Do anyone meet with this problem?)

Request to elasticsearch using Postman:

```
GET http://localhost/my-index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "address_object",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": {
                        "term": {"address_object.city": "Paris"}
                    }
                }
            },
            "inner_hits" : {}
        }
    }
}
```

Response with status code 200:

```
{
    "took": 161,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 2,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 1,
        "failures": [
            {
                "shard": 0,
                "index": "my-index",
                "node": "DWdD83KaTmUiodENQkGDww",
                "reason": {
                    "type": "null_pointer_exception",
                    "reason": null
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 6500039,
        "max_score": 2.1761138,
        "hits": []
    }
}
```

Elasticsearch version: 6.2.4

Lucene version: 7.2.1

**Update:**

Mapping:

```
{
    "my-index": {
        "mappings": {
            "mytype": {
                "dynamic": "false",
                "_source": {
                    "enabled": false
                },
                "properties": {
                    "adverts_count": {
                        "type": "integer",
                        "store": true
                    },
                    ...
                    "address_object": {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "properties": {
                            "adverts_count": {
                                "type": "integer",
                                "store": true
                            },
                            "city": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "store": true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    ...
```

**Sample document:**

```
{
   "_index": "my-index",
   "_type": "mytype",
   "_id": "XDWrGncBdwNBWGEagAM2",
   "_score": 2.1587489,
   "fields": {
      "is_target_page_shown": [
         0
      ],
      "updated_at": [
         1612264276
      ],
      "is_shown": [
         0
      ],
      "nb_queries": [
         1
      ],
      "search_query": [
         "phone"
      ],
      "target_category": [
         15
      ],
      "adverts_count": [
         1
      ]
   }
}
```

**Extra information:**

- If I remove the `"inner_hits": {}` from search request, elastic returns nested documents(_index, _type, _id, _score), but ain't other fields(e.g city)
- Also, as suggested in the comments, I tried setting to true ignore_unmapped, but it doesn't helped. The same nullPointerException.

Comment: Can you share your mapping and sample documents

Comment: if you see resoponse `"failed": 1` carefully then it shows that one of your `shards` is failing. I think so issue is due to that only.

Comment: Can you please set `"ignore_unmapped": true` to your `nested` query and check.

Comment: @Amit can you please check? I updated the question context

Comment: @BeketBerikuly, i provided my answer, let me know if you have followup questions, mostly you don't have a proper document in your Elasticsearch index

Comment: @BeketBerikuly did you get a chance to look at my answer?

Comment: @Amit it doesn't helped to me. Update: If I remove the `"inner_hits": {}` from search request, elastic returns nested documents(_index, _type, _id, _score), but ain't other fields(e.g city)

Answer (score 0):

I tried reproducing your issue, but as you have not provided the proper sample documents(one which you provided doesn't have the `address_object` properties), I used your mapping and below sample documents.

```
PUT index-name/_doc/1
{
    "address_object" :{
        "adverts_count" : 1,
        "city": "paris"
    }
}
PUT index-name/_doc/2
{
    "address_object" :{
        "adverts_count" : 1,
        "city": "blr"
    }
}
```

And when I use the same search provided by you.

```
POST 71907588/_search
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "address_object",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": {
                        "term": {
                            "address_object.city": "paris"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "inner_hits": {}
        }
    }
}
```

I get a proper response, matching `paris` as city as shown in the search response.

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "71907588",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.6931471,
                "_source": {
                    "address_object": {
                        "adverts_count": 1,
                        "city": "paris"
                    }
                },
                "inner_hits": {
                    "address_object": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": {
                                "value": 1,
                                "relation": "eq"
                            },
                            "max_score": 0.6931471,
                            "hits": [
                                {
                                    "_index": "71907588",
                                    "_id": "1",
                                    "_nested": {
                                        "field": "address_object",
                                        "offset": 0
                                    },
                                    "_score": 0.6931471,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "city": "paris",
                                        "adverts_count": 1
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
```